# Why do we need to install a kit (JDK) to start programming in Java

Tags: java, python, compilation, ide

My first programming language was Pascal and I did not have to install more than just the compiler. Same thing with C++, the environment was all set to write code by just installing Visual Studio. 
In the case of Java why do we need to install this Java Development Kit besides having the Eclipse, Netbeans or another compiler.

I think that Python and Perl have also a packet to be installed before writing code in those languages. Otherwise we wouldn't be able to start off. What do these packets contain and why some languages require these files to be installed before compiling any code.

Comment: You are wrong, first you needed to install the OS. Some good OSes install with a compiler built-in.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. That means, Windows, has a C++ or a C compiler already installed? Thank you

Comment: @ChristianJaimes No Windows does not have a compiler built in (Nor really do Unixes some just happen to have a C compiler as a tool that the install includes but not really part of the OS but you can run the OS without a compiler )

Comment: @mark The time where hardware costs were significant higher than a software, and the software distributed along with the hardware always include a source code to be ported to this platform during installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal Java package (the JRE) only contains the stuff necessary to run Java programmes. The JDK *is* the package containing the compiler. Based on your experience with Pascal and C++, you obviously understand why you need the compiler to create your own programmes.

Eclipse and Netbeans are IDEs, Integrated Developement Enviroments. They make it easier for you to program, but they are not strictly needed, in the same way that you can write a program in C++ by just installing a C++ compiler and without using Visual Studio. There are many programmers, especially in the non-windows-world, who just use a text editor to write those programmes.

As for Python and Perl, it's the same thing. You need to install their respecitve interpreters to run programmes written in those languages. Without them, how do you expect the computer to understand what you want from it?

If you want compare, for example, Eclipse and Visual Studio: the installation for Visual Studio contains both the IDE *and* the compiler. Eclipse is *just* the IDE. You also need to install the compiler, which is contained in the JDK.

Comment: That assumes that Eclipse is just for Java - you can use it for Python so does not include the computer + some eclipse installs include the JDE)

Comment: True. I wrote my anser that way because OP didn't seem to understand the difference between compilers and IDEs that much, and I didn't want to make it harder on him. If they learn that some versions of Eclipse and Netbeans also offer the option to install compilers, all the better.

Comment: Thank you Carsten. Your answer is very clear. I do understand the difference between compiler and IDEs, but I was not associating them the way you did when you say that Visual Studio contains both IDE and the compiler. That definitely cleared up my doubt.

Comment: That means, if I uninstall the JDK I would not have a "translator" between my code and the machine. It would not be enough with Eclipse, because compiling simply is not the role of Eclipse, which is just and IDE. Right? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With Pascal and C++ the compiler and related tools will convert the source code into machine code that will directly run on the hardware when called from the Operating System,

In Java, Python and Perl the tools generate an intermediate code that does not run directly on the hardware, you need a runtime which is the executable that the operating system calls. This executable will read the intermediate code and convert it to machine language. In Java this is the JRE called java.exe, python is python.exe etc (in non Windows/DOS oS the .exe is not there as not required for executables). In Java you see the intermediate code as .cls files or packed into jars/wars etc and have to explicitly compile the Java to these. Python and perl usually do the compile implicitly, python files show as .pyc and others

Comment: Thanks!! your answer is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

JDK (Java Development Kit) contains the tools required to develop aplications such as the Java compiler. 
As seen in the 
["Java SE Downloads"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)  page:

> Software Developers: JDK (Java SE Development Kit). For Java Developers. **Includes a complete JRE plus tools for developing, debugging, and monitoring Java applications.**

Java is quite different than the languages you mentioned. I like this slight difference to be honnes, it clears things up a lot. If you want to develop, you have to download the JDK otherwise you download a much lighter package which is the JRE that is included in the JDK.

I hope this answers the question :- )

Comment: Except on OS X you need the JDK to run java applications - JRE just does Java applets

Comment: Wouldn't that be enough with the IDE? If I uninstall the JDK but I keep Eclipse, would I still be able to run code? I'm trying to understand why the JDK is essential. Thank you guys.

Comment: Eclipse does not usually contain the JRE or if it does it is really only for Eclipse

Comment: @Mark Ah, i didnt know that... never had OS X :( Thanks!
As far as i know JDK is not required for Eclipse, since it contains its own compiler but personally i install it instead of the JRE because i am using other tools such as the javadoc command that doesnt exist in the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Writing Java applets and applications needs development tools like JDK. The JDK includes the Java Runtime Environment, the Java compiler and the Java APIs. For Java Developers. Includes a complete JRE plus tools for developing, debugging, and monitoring Java applications.

Comment: Wouldn't that be enough with the IDE?  If I uninstall the JDK but I keep Eclipse, would I still be able to run code? I'm trying to understand why the JDK is essential. 
Thank you Malf.